# Adding extra column to view, which is not present in table - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created the following column in my table; I am aware that I can't set a PK on my view.

```
    [Row_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_SPCO_PSP_test] 
         PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Row_ID] ASC)
                     WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                           IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                           ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I need to have the same column in my view so the following works:

```
SELECT table_name.*
FROM table_name
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM view_name 
                  WHERE view_name.Row_ID = table_name.Row_ID);
```

- `Row_ID` is not a hard coded value so something like `'24' Row_ID` will not work. `Row_ID` assigns a unique value to each row
- How do I create column `[Row_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL` in my view?

Comment: When would `view_name.Row_ID` be different from `table_name.Row_ID`?

Comment: What you're doing doesn't seem to make sense.
Can you break it down to a simple example that you can post instead of just snippets of your actual tables. What exactly is your view and why would it not have data from the (presumably) underlying table?

Comment: There are 4 tables. I have a query that joins all four tables to create another table. I use the same query to create a view. The view has the latest data and I want to incrementally upload the data from the view to the table, but to do this I need a Unique identifier (Row_ID) that is the same on both table and view. I already have Row_ID on my table but I can't figure out how to create this column on the view.

Comment: Well where do you want the RowID to come from? A view doesn't exist independently, it's just a representation of a query.

Comment: You state you have four tables that join have joined in a query. On one table, you have define `[Row_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL`. What about the other three tables? Do they have unique identifiers (primary keys)? If so, your unique view row id can be a constructed composite of the four table keys - something like `CONCAT(Table1.Row_ID, ':', Table2.Key, ':', Table3.Key, ':', Table4.Key)`. (The `:` is an arbitrary delimiter not otherwise present in the keys.) See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/w-WrQYM1).

Answer (score 0):

You can create such column in the view using ROW_NUMBER, but you will have no guarantee it is the same as this in your data table.

In order to be sure, you need unique identifier build from the initial SELECT - it can be the PK of one of the tables or combinations of their PK.

Then, when you need to perform CRUD on the data table based on the view data, you will use this PK as condition to match if a row exist or now (or should be updated).

Alternative is to use EXCEPT. It will be something like the following:

I created the following column on my table: *I am aware that I can't set a PK on my view.

```
[Row_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
```

CONSTRAINT [PK_SPCO_PSP_test] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
[Row_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
I need to have the same column in my view so the following works:

```
INSERT INTO table_name
SELECT *
FROM view_name
EXEPT
SELECT *
FROM table_name
```

but of course it can be slower and you have less control.